# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null at text inside this blog website I'm trying to write

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var x = 0;

function text() {
  var blogtext = document.getElementById("Textarea").value;
  var y = "p" + String(x);
  console.log(typeof y);
  //problem
  document.createElement("p").id = y;
  //
  document.getElementById(y).innerHTML = blogtext;
  //document.write("<p>"+blogtext+"<p>");
  x = x + 1;
}
```

When I run this code inside an HTML file the error: `Uncaught TypeError` occurs, the code is supposed to create a new paragraph tag whose content is the text inputted by the user inside the text area and each paragraph would have a different id as x increases. 
Sorry, I'm new to coding this is one of my school's projects.

Comment: means it can not find the element..... You did not append it to the document. Also no reason to look it up to set the innerHTML since you already have the reference to the element.

Comment: You created the element, yet did not append it to the DOM. Just assign the return of `createElement()` to a variable and you can skip the `getElementById()` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not creating the element right and you are looking for the element before it is added to the page.

```
var x = 0;
function text() {
    var blogtext = document.getElementById("Textarea").value;
    var y = "p" + String(x);
    // create the element
    var p = document.createElement("p")
    //set the id
    p.id = y;
    //set the html
    p.innerHTML = blogtext;
    // add it to the page
    // document.getElementById("outputId").appendChild(p)
    document.body.appendChild(p)
    x = x + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

append your paragraph to the DOM, check out for this one i made

```
 var x = 0;
function text() {
    var blogtext = document.getElementById("Textarea").value;
    var y = "p" + String(x);
    console.log(typeof y);
    var x =document.createElement("p").id = y;
    document.body.appendChild(x);
    document.getElementById(y).innerHTML = blogtext;
    x = x + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You made a few omissions in your code and just a bit of cleanup solves your problem

```js
var x = 0;

function text() {
  var blogtext = document.getElementById("Textarea").value;
  var y = "p" + String(x);
  console.log(typeof y);
  //solution
 var p = document.createElement("p")
 document.body.append(p)
 p.setAttribute("id",y)
  //
 p.innerHTML = blogtext;
  //document.write("<p>"+blogtext+"<p>");
  x = x + 1;
  console.log()
} 

//text()
```

```html
<textarea id="Textarea" onChange=text()></textarea> <br>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not creating and appending the element coreectly

```js
    var x = 0;

    function text() {
      var blogtext = document.getElementById("Textarea").value;
      var y = "p" + String(x);
      console.log(typeof y);

     var elem = document.createElement("p")
     document.body.append(elem)
     elem.id = y

     elem.innerHTML = blogtext;

      x = x + 1;
      console.log()
    }
```